# Nightwatch js how to assert multiple elements

Tags: javascript, selenium, accessibility, functional-testing, nightwatch.js

i'm trying to assert/verify multiple elements for an attribute with Nightwatch.js.

I tried to use the "elements" command by selenium but it seems to not actually return a tag.

```
browser.elements('css selector','icon_checkmark', function (result) {
    this.verify.attributeEquals(result.value, 'aria-hidden', 'true');
})
```

The console outputs this error:

```
Testing if attribute aria-hidden of <[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]> equals "true". 
Element could not be located.  - expected "true" but got: null
ERROR: Unable to locate element: "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" using: css selector
```

It seems like it finds the right things because there should be 6 but then somehow I read out the wrong thing? Console.log of result.value[0] gives just { ELEMENT: '19' } which seems correct.

Any idea how could I make this work? I want to check if all elements with the class icon_checkmark have an attribute aria-hidden="true".

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/:sessionId/elements – "Returns:
{Array.<{ELEMENT:string}>} A list of WebElement JSON objects for the located elements."
unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to get the actual element by the "The opaque ID assigned to the element by the server".

Comment: I can't figure it out either but I made it a little further: https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/512

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`attributeEquals` locate element using css selector, while `elements` returns `ID` of element, so you can't locate the element that way. You can use `elementIdAttribute` to get the element and verify it.

```
browser.elements('css selector','icon_checkmark', function (result) {
  result.value.map(function (v, k) {
    browser.elementIdAttribute(v.ELEMENT, 'aria-hidden', function (res) {
      // true
      return browser.assert.equal(res.value, 'expected value');
    });
  });
})
```

Answer (score -3):

result.value is an array.  so you would need to loop through the array result.value[x]